# Usi e significato della parola "locazione"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

Durante la mia vita ho occasionalmente usato la parola "locazione" per indicare un luogo (ad esempio "la mia locazione attuale è Milano"), praticamente come se fosse la traduzione della parola inglese "location".
Qualche tempo fa mi è stato fatto notare che in italiano "locazione" si riferisce esclusivamente a contratti d'affitto.

Il vocabolario online Treccani riporta, oltre al significato di contratto d'affitto, anche l'utilizzo in informatica per indicare una locazione di memoria su un calcolatore (e probabilmente, visto il mio background da programmatore, questo deve essere il motivo per cui mi sono ritrovato ad usare la parola locazione in altri contesti). http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/locazione/

Cercando ulteriormente su internet in effetti la parola locazione viene praticamente usata solo per indicare un contratto. Sono riuscito a trovare un esempio di "locazione" usato per indicare un luogo qui: https://context.reverso.net/traduzione/francese-italiano/location

> location de gare routière à DP Děčín
>   la locazione di una stazione di autobus a DP Děčín

O perlomeno, suppongo sia tale perchè non credo si possano affittare stazioni di autobus.

Ho anche trovato questo: https://golarion.altervista.org/wiki/Incantesimi/Rivela_Locazioni Ma non vorrei che chi ha tradotto questa cosa dall'inglese abbia commesso il mio stesso errore.

Ciò che volevo sapere quindi è se la parola locazione, per quanto estremamente inusuale e conscio del fatto che se un vocabolario non riporta questo uso della parola è altamente improbabile che sia così, possa effettivamente essere usata per indicare un luogo.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: grazie per il benvenuto!

Comment: @valepu, come hai scritto anche tu nella domanda, in italiano la parola "locazione" si riferisce al contratto d'affitto di beni mobili o immobili ma si usa anche in informatica per indicare la porzione o cella in cui può essere suddivisa a livello logico una memoria informatica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personalmente non ho mai sentito quest'uso di "locazione", sospetto che tu faccia confusione con "ubicazione".
Gli esempi che hai trovato, come notavi, puzzano di cattiva traduzione dall'inglese (considera che il francese "location" ha lo stesso significato e la stessa diffusione dell'italiano "affitto").

Answer (score 3):

Come ti è stato detto, effettivamente la parola locazione in Italiano si riferisce esclusivamente ad un contratto di affitto e non viene mai usata con il concetto di posizione oppure (come correttamente indicato da @OldManOfAran) ubicazione.

La frase del tuo esempio diventerebbe:

> La mia posizione (oppure ubicazione) attuale è Milano

Peraltro nel contesto informatico l'espressione *locazione di memoria* si riferisce di fatto ad una specifica posizione della memoria stessa in cui sono salvate le informazioni.